# Synchronization in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, synchronization

I have two user controls in Silverlight application containing textboxes(1), how can i synchronize these textboxes when i start writing in one of those textboxes.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, that one updates the other? or that they have same content?

Comment: they should have same content .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#why_dependency_properties) in each control that changes the value of th text box, then bind on control to the value of the other.

example

```
           public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerTextProperty= 
                 DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InnerText", typeof(string),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnTextInput) );
public bool InnerText
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(InnerTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InnerTextProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnTextInput(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    YourControl c = obj as YourControl
    if(c != null)
    {
        c._innerTextBox.Text = e.Value;
    }

}
```

Comment: :Thanks for reply, but can please tell me how can i create dependency property if both the controls are in different user controls?